# ¿Cómo cortar un string hasta el slash anterior de la url?

Tags: javascript, string

Teniendo en cuenta cadena:

```
/carpeta_uno/carpeta_dos/carpeta_tres
```

Se necesita cortar hasta que quede:

```
/carpeta_uno/carpeta_dos
```

Esta tarea debe ser dinámica, por lo tanto debe retornar la cadena que representa la ruta a la carpeta de nivel superior cada vez que se invoca la función.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes efectuarlo, haciendo un split al texto y luego en el array eliminando el último item con `splice(splittedText.length - 1, 1)` y efectuando a posterior un join (unión) con el carácter que hemos separado "/"

```js
const aux = '**/carpeta_uno/carpeta_uno/carpeta_uno**';

const removeLastSplitItem = (text, splitChar) => {
  let splittedText = text.split(splitChar);
  
  // splice remove a item of array, get last index and remove this
  splittedText.splice(splittedText.length - 1, 1);
  
  return splittedText.join(splitChar);
}

console.log(removeLastSplitItem(aux, '/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo más rápido y sencillo es que busques la posición del último "/" y hagas un substring hasta esa posición.

El código sería el siguiente:

```js
var url = "/carpeta_uno/carpeta_uno/carpeta_uno";
var ultimaPosicion = url.lastIndexOf('/');
var nivelAnterior = url.substr(0, ultimaPosicion);
console.log(nivelAnterior);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion split() para picar la cadena, luego desechas la última posicion del array resultante del array resultante.

```
function backward(){
   var str = "/carpeta_uno/carpeta_dos/carpeta_tres";
   var array= str.split("/");
   var result= "/"
   for (i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
      text += array[i] + "/";
   }
   return result;
}
```